# Decomposition of Banach bimodules of Banach algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras, bimodules

Let $A$ and $B$ be Banach algebras, $\theta:A\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a character (i.e., a multiplicative linear functional) and $A\oplus _{\theta} B$ be the $l^1$-direct sum of $A$ and $B$ equipped with the multiplication given by 
$$(a,b)(a',b')=(aa',\theta(a)b'+\theta(a')b+bb')\quad(a,a'\in A, b,b'\in B).$$
If $M$ is a Banach $A\oplus_{\theta} B$-bimodule, is it always possible to decompose $M$ into direct sum of some Banach $A$-bimodule and Banach $B$-bimodule?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where is this multiplication arising? I kind of doubt that you will find this decomposition.

Comment: @ChrisRamsey This is the "Lau product" introduced by Mehdi Monfared in his PhD thesis. When  $B$ is unital it is actually isomorphic to the usual direct product/direct sum of algebras, a fact that seems to have escaped the notice of a large number of people who have worked on this. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07868

Comment: @YemonChoi Medhi, eh? A Canadian shoutout is the best kind of shoutout.

Comment: BTW, on a separate note, I just realised that you have also posted this question on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2492062/decomposition-of-banach-bimodules-of-banach-algebras It is generally considered good practice to **avoid** posting the same question on both sites, as this can lead people on one site to waste time answering a question that is being answered on the other one

Comment: @YemonChoi You are right. But the question will be seen by different persons... Could you please give a hint ( or some reference ) to find such a decomposition?